# how to negate any alphanumeric character with alnum in r (str_)

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I would like to rewrite the following regular expression in r by using `[:alnum:]`, that in my understanding should do the same thing:

`starwars %>% mutate(name = str_replace_all(name, "[^a-zA-Z\\d\\s:\u00C0-\u00FF]", ""))`

But the behaviour I get is not at all what I expected:

`starwars %>% mutate(name = str_replace_all(name, "[^:alnum:]", ""))`

By the way, I need to remove the underscores `_` and the all the spaces.

Comment: Looks like the pattern you need is `[\W_]+`,`str_replace_all(name, "[\\W_]+", "")`

Comment: You are always welcome. Note that I am a bit more inclined to using shorthand character classes since they are more portable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```r
library(stringr)
str_replace_all(name, "[^[:alnum:]]+", "")
## or
str_replace_all(name, "[:^alnum:]+", "")
```

The `[^[:alnum:]]` pattern is a negated *bracket expression* (`[^...]`) that matches any chars other than letters and digits (`[:alnum:]`, a POSIX character class).

The `[:^alnum:]` pattern is an extension of the POSIX character class with an inverse meaning.

The `+` is a quantifier, it matches one or more occurrences of the pattern it quantifies.

Also, in `stringr`, the shorthand character classes are Unicode aware, so you may also use

```r
str_replace_all(name, "[\\W_]+", "")
```

where `\W` matches any char other than Unicode letters, digits or underscores, and `_` matches underscores.

Comment: Why is the + needed here?

Comment: @DarioLacan Matching one or more occurrences.